PyQGIS - How to determine if two raster layers overlap
Is there a simple way to determine if two rasters overlap each other, relatively quickly?
I'm writing software to generate many viewsheds, using r.viewshed, and need a way to determine if the positive area (as below, in yellow) of two of these viewshed rasters overlap. You can see one of the rasters generated below. Many of these are generated and placed on the terrain. It would be great to have a way to determine if a raster is overlapping another, and which other rasters it overlaps.
One way I've been calculating this previously has been using the radius of each raster, and distance each raster is apart from each other, to determine if there would be a possible overlap, but this is not ideal, and takes a long time to calculate for each raster to every other raster.

Another method I've tried is sampling points from each raster but this is also not ideal, as it takes a while to iterate through.

The rasters overlap if their extents overlap. Or are you looking for whether a difference is not NODATA (which is very different, and can't be done quickly)

Yes, I'm trying to determine the overlap of the non-NODATA values of each raster. Is there no way to determine overlap of non-NODATA values quickly?

You could use Raster boolean AND algorithm in QGIS.
Prosessing tool box -> Raster Analysis -> Raster boolean AND
